# Which tft works on both Arduino Uno and Raspberry pi

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi, tft

Ideally I'd like a 2.8 inch and it to be touch screen. 
But most of all I'd rather it work on both boards without much hassle.

Comment: Uno works at 5V and Pi at 3.3V, keep that in mind. A display with SPI, I2C or uart is likely to work on both, given the right circuitry for the difference in voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Well any display can work on both of the boards if you can adjust the voltage levels right there is a display which was made for old Nokia phones and it is called nokia-5110-3310 and  is dirt cheap display and it can be used with both Arduino or raspberry pi or any other board which support the protocol here is a link for quick reference.

[Adafruit link to the library](https://learn.adafruit.com/nokia-5110-3310-lcd-python-library/overview)

Answer (score 0):

adafruit has a resistive touch screen which is 2.8" and works on most boards. Its 30 dollars and works well. It has instructions and all and libraries which you can use. Plug it into a breadboard, connect the jumpers and you're all set.

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1770

on the other hand, Elegoo has made a very similar product, which can also be used on most boards if you plug it into a breadboard, but it is specially designed for the UNO. You can plug it straight into the UNO board, without the need of breadboards. This comes with a instructional DVD and is only 12 dollars on Amazon. It is also a resistive screen and basically the same product.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EUVJYME/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EUVJYME)

Good luck!